# Java Method is broken

Tags: java, methods, return, compression, static-methods

I am trying to get it to return a compressed word. For example, reaction should be @act$. But it is getting returned as react$. I feel like my issue is not including the original word in  the return statement. Can anyone help? Thanks!

```
public static String compress (String word) {
      String newWord = "";
      int the = word.indexOf("the");
      if (the >= 0) {
         newWord = word.substring(0,the) + "&" + word.substring(the+3);
      }
      int ion = newWord.indexOf("ion");
      if (ion >= 0) {
         newWord = newWord.substring(0,ion) + "$" + word.substring(ion+3);
      }
      int ing = newWord.indexOf("ing");
      if (ing >= 0) {
         newWord = newWord.substring(0,ing) + "~" + word.substring(ing+3);
      }
      int an = newWord.indexOf("an");
      if (an >= 0) {
         newWord = newWord.substring(0,an) + "#" + word.substring(an+2);
      }
      int re = newWord.indexOf("re");
      if (re >= 0) {
         newWord = newWord.substring(0,re) + "@" + word.substring(re+2);
      }
      int con = newWord.indexOf("con");
      if (con >= 0) {
         newWord = newWord.substring(0,con) + "%" + word.substring(con+3);
      }
      return newWord;
   }
```

Answer (score 2):

A compressed version also:

```
public static String compress(String word) {
    word = word.replace("the", "&");
    word = word.replace("ion", "$");
    word = word.replace("ing", "~");
    word = word.replace("an", "#");
    word = word.replace("re","@");
    word = word.replace("con","%");    
    return word;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're mixing up your uses of `newWord` and `word` in a confusing way. If the first `if` clause doesn't fire, `newWord` will still be an empty string and none of the other conditions will fire. On the other hand, if `newWord` does get set to something, you still go on using `word` substrings, in ways that don't make any sense.

You would be better off just using one variable through the whole method.

```
public static String compress(String word) {
    int the = word.indexOf("the");
    if (the >= 0) {
        word = word.substring(0,the) + "&" + word.substring(the+3);
    }
    int ion = word.indexOf("ion");
    if (ion >= 0) {
        word = word.substring(0,ion) + "$" + word.substring(ion+3);
    }
    int ing = word.indexOf("ing");
    if (ing >= 0) {
        word = word.substring(0,ing) + "~" + word.substring(ing+3);
    }
    int an = word.indexOf("an");
    if (an >= 0) {
        word = word.substring(0,an) + "#" + word.substring(an+2);
    }
    int re = word.indexOf("re");
    if (re >= 0) {
        word = word.substring(0,re) + "@" + word.substring(re+2);
    }
    int con = word.indexOf("con");
    if (con >= 0) {
        word = word.substring(0,con) + "%" + word.substring(con+3);
    }
    return word;
}
```

Note also that, written this way, you can only use each replacement once per word: if you have `"thethe"` you will compress it to `"&the"`, not `"&&"`. If you want use replacements multiple times, you would have to use a loop. Or, easier still, use [`String.replace`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace(java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.CharSequence)).

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. I corrected the inconsistency but am still getting the same (wrong) output. Do you know what else it could be? I really appreciate your help. Also, we are only supposed to change the first occurrence of the phrase ("&the" would be correct).

Comment: @UNLVStudent1992 I just ran the code I posted on the string `"reaction"` and got `"@act$"`. If you get something else, you are doing something different.

Comment: Do you have any idea why mine would still be returning something different? Java is so frustrating to me. I tried the modifications you gave me and am still getting the same mistakes. Thank you for your help by the way, I really appreciate it.

Comment: The possible reasons are (1) you have written your code differently from what I wrote, (2) you are passing in different input (for instance, passing in a string with capital letters in it), (3) your program has not been recompiled.